# sync branch in two clones after rebasing

Tags: git

I've got a repo cloned on two machines, and working over some time in the same branch (branch "foo") on each. (Similar scenario: two people with clones working on the same branch.) I don't want to get too far behind on changes in the main branch, so will occasionally rebase the foo branch from main in one clone.

What's the best way to get the other clone in sync?

After the rebase in one clone, a force push is needed to update the remote. I can then fetch in the other clone. But if I try to pull, I'll have merge conflicts to contend with. I tried to pull with `--force` expecting that to work, but that still led to merge conflicts.

In the second clone, I could use `reset --hard` to back up to the last commit in main, and then do  a fast-forward merge of foo branch. Is that the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Why not just `git fetch`? This causes your local repo's remote-tracking branches to be identical to the remote you are fetching from. They are now absolutely in sync! If you then don't like the way a local branch `foo` looks, reset it hard to `origin/foo`, which is what you just fetched.

Comment: `git fetch` will sync the remote-tracking branch in a clone with the remote. But it doesn't sync the local branch to that. But you're saying that `git reset --hard origin/foo` will just move the head for foo to the same commit as origin/foo, effectively orphaning the diverging commits in foo? So effectively equivalent to `git reset --hard <earlier commit>` followed by `git pull`?

Comment: There is no need for git pull.

Comment: While `--force` is an acceptable option to `git pull`, that's only because it passes it to `git fetch` ... and in the *normal* setup, which you're using, the fetch step is already using the force option when updating remote-tracking names. So adding `--force` here has no effect at all, and you shouldn't do it. (You might do it for a very weird setup, or if you're running torture tests on your latest changes to the Git internals, but normal people shouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is almost always a matter of opinion, but I'm [with matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669604/sync-branch-in-two-clones-after-rebasing#comment123148576_69669604) on this one, at least for the first step or two: use `git fetch`.

Let's do this by example.  Suppose machine L is a Linux box, and machine M is a Mac, and you're working on software that runs on both, but needs occasional special-case code for the other system.  For development and testing, you're working on your feature branch now: branch `foo` (why not `feature`? who knows).

Anyway, here you are working on machine L, on branch `foo`.  You change some files and commit and build and test, and it almost works, so you make a few more changes and commit and build and test and now it works.  You go over to machine M and run `git fetch L` while on branch `foo`.  You're now strictly behind `L/foo`, so that:

```
M$ git rev-list --count --left-right L/foo...foo
```

prints "2 0" for instance.  So now you want to fast-forward to bring in the two commits.  I have an alias for this, `git mff`, but you can write:

```
M$ git merge --ff-only L/foo
```

and now you're up to date on M w.r.t. L.  You now build and test ... and find out that, dag-nab-it, the latest update doesn't *work* on macOS.  So you make some more changes and build and commit and test as needed.

But before it's all working, something makes you switch back to machine L.  While you're on L, you also add a new commit or two:

```
L$ git commit -m "fix major goof spotted on M"
...
```

Now, regardless of which machine you go to and run `git fetch`, your:

```
git rev-list --left-right --count M/foo...foo
```

or the same with `L/foo...foo` prints *two positive numbers*.  That is, *both computers are ahead of each other* (as well as being behind each other).

Since you don't like a merge-oriented work-flow, you must now pick one of the two machines on which to use `git rebase`:

```
L$ git rebase M/foo
```

and now your Linux machine is strictly ahead of the mac and hence on the mac you'll run `git fetch L; git reset --hard L/foo` and be even; or:

```
M$ git rebase L/foo
```

and now your mac is strictly ahead of the Linux box and hence on the Linux box you'll run `git fetch M; git reset --hard M/foo` and be even.

The one thing you *don't* want to do is:

```
git reset --hard L/foo
```

from M, for instance, if you *haven't* put the M commits onto L first, via rebasing there.  So you will definitely need to keep track of which machine is "ahead of" the other, and will probably want to set the upstream of `foo` to `L/foo` on M, set the upstream of `foo` to `M/foo` on L, and make heavy use of `git status` or similar to get those `git rev-list --count --left-right` numbers.  Those are what `git status` prints as "ahead", "behind", or "diverged" numbers (depending on status output format and other personal settings).

Comment: your answer isn't the easiest to follow. Best practice for questions is to provide a minimally sufficient case to describe a problem; same should apply to answers.